# Acer Aspire reports 432MB RAM but has 1GB installed

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

My Acer Aspire has 1GB RAM (2x512MB)
When running Ubuntu 11.10, it only reports having 432MB. This would be corect if I was only using 512MB of RAM.

Before the upgrade, it showed the correct amount of memory and performed much faster

Comment: Maybe one of the RAM broke during the install. Try to boot with only one 512mb stick. If both works then there is another problem.
Also try one port first the the other, just to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

There are two senarios that has happened either something is wrong with your **RAM DIMMs** or something is wrong with the **software** on your computer.

**RAM DIMMS:**

- try to remove one at the time to see which one of them is working or
  not. (just to be sure)

**The system:**

- Go into BIOS and reset all settings to default. Remember your old settings... Just in case

By the way, what does BIOS say of your amount of RAM?

*If this doesn't work, add a comment and let me know.*

Comment: The commendation of BIOS reset can get you into trouble, dont. If the system reads the correct amount during POST it really doesn't mater the BIOS settings.

Answer (score 0):

Does the bios report the same amount of ram? When you boot the computer, and before reaching grub screen you should see messages reporting the ram, hard drive, etc detected. If the ram detected is wrong there, then the problem is in the bios, not ubuntu.

I had this problem before. Sometimes removing and installing the ram again from the mother board solves it. And sometimes resetting the bios to default forces it to detect the ram properly.

Goog luck!

Comment: By the way: The fact than the operative system reports less than 512 is normal, it means than from 512 mb, a percent is reserved for system processes and is not available to the user. For example I have 1024 Mb installed, and so tells me tye bios, but ubuntu tells me I have 997. Your problem must be with the other 512 Mb. Cheers.